# Retrieve attribute using ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
*import java.util.*;  
public class UserArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creating user defined class objects  
        Student s1=new Student(1,"AAA",13);  
        Student s2=new Student(2,"BBB",14);  
        Student s3=new Student(3,"CCC",15); 
        ArrayList<Student> al=new ArayList<Student>();
        al.add(s1);
        al.add(s2);  
        al.add(s3);  
        Iterator itr=al.iterator();  
        //traverse elements of ArrayList object  
        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            Student st=(Student)itr.next();  
            System.out.println(st.rollno+" "+st.name+" "+st.age);  
        }  
    }
}
class Student{  
    int rollno;  
    String name;  
    int age;  
    Student(int rollno,String name,int age){  
        this.rollno=rollno;  
        this.name=name;  
        this.age=age;  
    }  
}
```

How do I retrieve a single attribute of Student class using ArrayList or check whether "AAA" is present in the list?

Comment: Why would you tag this JavaScript when it's not that

Comment: If you are using Java 8 you can use : `Student find = al.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.name.equals("AAA"))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);`

Comment: "_or check whether "AAA" is present in the list?_" This part is easy: in the while-loop you already have, you can use `if("AAA".equals(st.name))`. I would suggest adding getter and setter methods to your `Student`-DTO, though. In which case `.name` becomes `.getName()`.

Comment: You did it in your code acutally. Inside System.out.println you get st.name. All you have to do is just do st.name.equals("AAA");

Answer (score 2):

Just added two lines and btw. you have error in that code when you create ArrayList. You wrote "ArayList" which is wrong.

**Method 1.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Creating user defined class objects  
            Student s1=new Student(1,"AAA",13);  
            Student s2=new Student(2,"BBB",14);  
            Student s3=new Student(3,"CCC",15); 
            ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>(); // YOU HAVE MISTAKE HERE ArayList<Student>()
            al.add(s1);
            al.add(s2);  
            al.add(s3);  
            Iterator itr=al.iterator();  
            //traverse elements of ArrayList object  
            while(itr.hasNext()){  
                Student st=(Student)itr.next();  
                System.out.println(st.rollno+" "+st.name+" "+st.age);  
                if(st.name.equals("AAA"))  // LINE ADDED
                    System.out.println("present!"); // LINE ADDED

            }  
        }
    }
    class Student{  
        int rollno;  
        String name;  
        int age;  
        Student(int rollno,String name,int age){  
            this.rollno=rollno;  
            this.name=name;  
            this.age=age;  
        }
```

**Method 2 -> Java 8 or higher**

```
  Student find = al.stream().filter(s -> s.name.equals("AAA")).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if(find != null)
            System.out.println("AAA is present");
```